# Утечка памяти из-за большого числа экземпляров org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem

Tags: java, утечка-памяти, wildfly

Я проапгрейдил приложение: 
- Spring, Spring Security: 3.2.10.RELEASE -> 5.0.7.RELEASE
- Hibernate: 4.2.0.Final -> 5.2.17.Final

Мы используем WildFly 15.0.1.Final. При деплое java-приложения возникает утечка памяти. Сняли хип-дамп, проанализировали с помощью MAT. В отчете говорится следующее:

```
1 860 instances of "org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem", loaded by "org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader @ 0x6c2c43270" occupy 206 395 072 (39,92 %) bytes. These instances are referenced from one instance of "java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]", loaded by "<system class loader>"
```

При деплое того же приложения (после апгрейда) на WildFly 10 подобной утечки не возникает.
Пробовали менять настройки флая, даже выделяли больше памяти (понимаю, что решение весьма так себе) - результата нет. Можете ли подсказать, в чем может быть проблема? Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема оказалась в версии SpringSession, нормально работающей под Spring 3, но не очень - под Spring 5. Именно его объекты в итоге обнаружились в недрах ConcurrentHashMap, которые плодил флай. Проблема решилась апгрейдом SpringSession с 2.0.2 до 2.1.8.